# Why did not delete DB record in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

working with Laravel 5.6 and I am going to delete table record from uploads images  table.
this is controller

```
 public function deleteOneImage($id)
    {
        Upload::where('id', $id)->delete();
        return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Image deleted successfully');
    }
```

and delete link in edit.blade.php

```
 <a class="button is-outlined" href="/myads/{{$upload->id}}/delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this record?')" >Delete</a></td>
```

and route

```
Route::get('myads/{uploads}/delete', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\VehicleController@deleteOneImage',
]);
```

but when I clicked delete buttons it does not delete the table records? how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Take the double curly brackets out.

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` and show the output with your route

Comment: Put dd($id) on your method check your function properly getting the parameter

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta in My route list I have above route

Comment: then put `dd($id)` in your first line of funtion and check its showing the right id

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta i did this dd($id) then encount this error msg **syntax error, unexpected 'Upload' (T_STRING)**

Comment: ohh man put a semicolon `(;)` at the last

Comment: then no any error here

Comment: how can I check properly getting the parameter using dd($id);

Comment: what you are seeing on `dd($id);`

Comment: No any thing same page here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work:

```
<a class="button is-outlined" href="{{url('myads/'. $upload->id .'/delete')}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this record?')" >Delete</a>
```

Comment: it is same thing here

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope this will help you.

in your blade:

```
<a onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('{{md5($upload->id."delete")}}').submit();">Delete</a>

<form id="{{md5($upload->id.'delete')}}" action="{{ route('myads.destroy',$upload->id) }}" method="POST">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
</form>
```

And change your route like this:

```
Route::delete('myads/{uploads}','VehicleController@deleteOneImage',)->name('myads.destroy');
```

And write this in controller:

```
public function deleteOneImage($id)
    {
        Upload::findOrFail($id)->delete();
        return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Image deleted successfully');
    }
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: got this error **Undefined variable: data (View: C:\Users\ddddd\Desktop\testing\frtg\resources\views\vehicles\edit.blade.php)

Comment: let me see your controller, controller for indexing the data, the ***$data*** its just an example it can be different, depend on what you type in controller

Comment: @Muru I have been edit my answer, and you can test it tell me if it works